# How to extract the keys of an Array and push them to a String array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, key-value, array-splice

Everyone else usually asking how to convert string array with commas to an array of key value pairs.

But my question is **opposite**. I want to **extract** the **keys** of the array and place them in a separate **array** using **PHP**

I have an array of this form:

> Array
> (
>
> [Lights] => 4
>
> [Tool Kit] => 4
>
> [Steering Wheel] => 4
>
> [Side Mirrors] => 3.5
>
> )

and I want **output** to be in this form:

```js
 {"Lights", "Tool Kit", "Steering Wheel", "Side Mirrors" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **array_keys**. It will return array keys as array values

```
$array=array('Lights' => 4,
'Tool Kit' => 4,
'Steering Wheel' => 4,
'Side Mirrors' => 3.5);

$key_array=array_keys($array);
print_r($key_array);
```

It will result

```
Array ( [0] => Lights [1] => Tool Kit [2] => Steering Wheel [3] => Side Mirrors )
```

Comment: Thanks.it worked. And Can I select only first few items of an array and push them to a new array? Like if I want only Lights and Tool Kit from index 0 and 1 to a new array. How can I?

Comment: Use $key_array=array_slice($key_array, 0, 2); to show first 2 elements

Answer (score 2):

Using **[array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)** :

> array_keys — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

So you can just extract each keys simply by using this method

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
```

Otherwise, you can **loop through each values** and only get the keys :

```
$keyArray=array_keys($array);

$keyArray=[];
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $keyArray[]=$key;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are expecting `JSON` output. You can just use `json_encode` function in a pair with `array_keys`.

```php
$result = json_encode(array_keys($array));
```

However, your result will be `["Lights","Tool Kit","Steering Wheel","Side Mirrors"]`